# Cambiar el object key cuando borro otra key del object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Me ha surgido un problema bastante molesto a estas alturas de mi proyecto (casi terminado).

Resulta que sin darme cuenta he guardado un objecto pensando que era un array. Hasta aquí la solución seria "Bueno pues convierte el objeto en array y ya está". Bien, esa solución no me sirve porque ese objecto interactúa con otras funciones de la app.

## La pregunta

¿Puedo hacer que un objeto tenga el comportamiento de un array al borrarle un index?
Es decir, pongamos que tengo un array:

```
let array = [0,1,2,3];
/** Las keys del array serian
 0:0
 1:1
 2:2
 3:3                              
 */
array.splice(2,1);
// el array quedaria de esta manera [0,1,3]
/** Las keys del array serian
 0:0
 1:1
 2:3

 */
```

Ahora tengo un objeto:

```
let obj = {0:1,1:2,2:3,3:4};
/**
 Si le elimno el index 2, el objeto quedaría de esta manera
 {0:1,1:2,3:4}

 */
```

Lo que quiero es que al eliminar el index 2, el index 3 pase a tener el nombre del index 2 (como el comportamiento del array)

No me importa cambiar el nombre de la key porque son numéricas (0,1,2...) en mi base de datos mongo. Lo único que necesito es que lleven un orden seguido 0,1,2,3... y no 0,2,3,4.

Por si sirve de ayuda el objeto lo guardo en mongo (por si mongo tiene alguna función que cambie los index y yo desconozca)

Si se necesita mas código o explicaciones, pedirlo, intenté que fuera lo mas claro posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los objetos no tienen indice, tampoco tienen orden garantizado, tienen propiedades y valores. Si quieres que las propiedades sean una sucesión de números, puedes reconstruir el objeto usando el índice de un array como propiedad, en este ejemplo puedes usar `Object.entries` y `.reduce`, usando el index de reduce puedes darle el nuevo nombre a las propiedades.

```js
let obj = {0:"uno",1:"dos",2:3,3:4};

delete obj[2];

const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((p,c,i)=>{
  p[i]=c[1];// <-- el nombre de la nueva propiedad es i
  return p;
},{});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Vale esto me empieza a servir, me coloca las keys 0,1,2 pero, los values me los revienta, mis values son textos, y me pone numeros. Lo que quiero es que solo cambien las keys, no los values (eso si, se va la key 2, el value 2 se va con el)

Comment: en el ejemplo los values son números, si obj tiene como valores strings va a poner strings

Comment: Correcto, era la respuesta de mongo que me la liaba, muchas gracias.